# Retrieving WiFi data with Python on Android

Tags: android, python, wifi, sl4a, android-wireless

I'm looking to get my WiFi signal strength on Android using Python. I can't seem to find any Python wifi monitoring modules that aren't operating system specific.

Comment: Why are you programming with python in Android? Seems like this would be much easier with the Android SDK and Java.

Comment: @Mozoby Yes it would be easier, how ever that's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the nature of what you are trying to do, you are going to have to use and Android specific wifi library, which may or may not exist. This is the closest thing I could find which includes a wifi_scan() function which will return signal strength.

http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/android/